# Arba'im Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred forty?

### ארבעים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 340? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 340, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Please don't put anything named "lazy gematria" there in the answer box.

Comment: We're getting so close to the number of days in a year that "days without X" is probably going to be pretty useful.

Comment: @DoubleAA ... and getting that much closer to being able to publish a desk calendar!

Comment: @IsaacMoses http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications

Comment: @DonielF And more to the point: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/3913/2

Comment: @IsaacMoses Accept and move on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Medrash Raba Braishis 26:4 - see Eitz Yosef at the bottom](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14385&st=&pgnum=62) says that from the end of the Mabul until the Dor Haflaga was 340 years.

Comment: How could that be if Peleg died after 340 years and his name was Peleg because of the Tower of Bavel? וּלְעֵ֥בֶר יֻלַּ֖ד שְׁנֵ֣י בָנִ֑ים שֵׁ֣ם הָֽאֶחָ֞ד פֶּ֗לֶג כִּ֤י בְיָמָיו֙ נִפְלְגָ֣ה הָאָ֔רֶץ וְשֵׁ֥ם אָחִ֖יו יָקְטָֽן

Comment: @DoubleAA, see _Rashi_ to that verse.

Comment: The Mabul was in 1656 and the Dor Hafelagah was in 1996. See Rashi to AZ 9a.

Answer (score 5):

340 are the fewest days in a year without a [mandatory](http://ph.yhb.org.il/10-17-02/) Shehechiyanu blessing for everyone in the Diaspora.

353 days in the shortest year - 1,2,10,15,16,22,23 Tishrei - 25 Kislev - 14 Adar [II] - 15,16 Nisan - 6,7 Sivan = 340

Answer (score 3):

The Jerusalem Talmud, [*Sh'viis* 4](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r1504.htm):8, cites Deuteronomy 28:40 ("כִּי יִשַּׁל זֵיתֶךָ", "when your olive will fall away") and says that it means that 1/340 of the olives will survive. (Talmud commentaries ad loc. note that the *gimatriya* of "יִשַּׁל" is 340.)

Answer (score 3):

Per [Genesis 11](http://chabad.org/8175):10–19, *Peleg* died 2+35+30+34+30+209=340 years after the deluge.

Comment: something is off http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/78089/759

Comment: @DoubleAA see _Rashi_ to 10:25.

Answer (score 3):

[Seder Hadoros Elef Hashlishi - volume 1 page 49](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46817&st=&pgnum=72&hilite=) says that of the 400 men Eisav gathered to attack Yaakov, 340 were from the "Bnei Se'ir Hachori".

Answer (score 2):

340 "chosen men", along with their chief, were killed, among a community of Christians that refused to embrace Judaism, in the 520s in Yemen, according to legend. Source: [*Jewish Encyclopedia*](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/5159-msh210)

Answer (score 2):

In 1896, the synagogue in [the Lange Wĳngaardstraat in Haarlem](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Lange+Wijngaardstraat,+Haarlem,+Netherlands/@52.3828435,4.6342224,17z) was enlarged to 340 seats. ([Source.](https://www.dutchjewry.org/drieluik/haarlem/haarlem.shtml))